# Juniper Network Connect "session terminated unexpectedly" after Mac Yosemite upgrade

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite, vpn, juniper-network-connect

Juniper Network Connect is not working since I have upgraded my mac to Yosemite. I have read and followed different forums and related question such as :

https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151141/juniper-network-connect-hangs-at-establishing-secure-session-after-upgrading-t

but no luck. Here is the log trace:

```
    2015-06-01 12:59:04.180 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: loading https://ras.optus.com.au/dana-na/auth/url_default/login.cgi... (DSLoginWindowController.m:257)
2015-06-01 12:59:04.181 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: setting cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:04 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:270)
2015-06-01 12:59:04.642 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: loaded https://ras.optus.com.au/dana-na/auth/url_default/welcome.cgi?p=user-confirm&id=state_017a96523263fd3962e541d8967f80ae (DSLoginWindowController.m:412)
2015-06-01 12:59:04.642 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -clearUserAgentCookie removing cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:04 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:1006)
2015-06-01 12:59:08.819 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: loading https://ras.optus.com.au/dana-na/auth/url_default/login.cgi... (DSLoginWindowController.m:257)
2015-06-01 12:59:08.819 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: setting cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:08 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:270)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.282 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: loading https://ras.optus.com.au/dana-na/html/blank.html... (DSLoginWindowController.m:257)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.283 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -clearUserAgentCookie removing cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:08 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:1006)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.284 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: setting cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:270)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.302 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: loaded https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/home/starter.cgi (DSLoginWindowController.m:412)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.303 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -clearUserAgentCookie removing cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:1006)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.303 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: found DSID cookie in WebKit cache after page load (DSLoginWindowController.m:435)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.303 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Adding cookie with name DSID, domain ras.optus.com.au, and value <hidden> (DSSessionContext.m:81)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.304 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Creating a new DSID cookie (DSSessionContext.m:145)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.327 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: loading https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/home/index.cgi... (DSLoginWindowController.m:257)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.327 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: setting cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:270)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.437 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: loaded https://ras.optus.com.au/dana-na/html/blank.html (DSLoginWindowController.m:412)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.438 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -clearUserAgentCookie removing cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:1006)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.443 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: found DSID cookie in WebKit cache after page load (DSLoginWindowController.m:435)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.443 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Adding cookie with name DSID, domain ras.optus.com.au, and value <hidden> (DSSessionContext.m:81)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.568 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: loaded https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/home/index.cgi (DSLoginWindowController.m:412)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.568 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -clearUserAgentCookie removing cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:1006)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.568 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: found DSID cookie in WebKit cache after page load (DSLoginWindowController.m:435)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.568 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Adding cookie with name DSID, domain ras.optus.com.au, and value <hidden> (DSSessionContext.m:81)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.569 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Creating a new DSID cookie (DSSessionContext.m:145)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.569 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -loginWindowController:didLoadContents:ofURL: redirecting to https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/nc/ncappletwindow.cgi?param_action=install&url=&w=&win_url=&noapplet=1... (NCController.m:1230)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.570 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: loading https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/nc/ncappletwindow.cgi?param_action=install&url=&w=&win_url=&noapplet=1... (DSLoginWindowController.m:257)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.570 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: setting cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:270)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.669 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: loaded https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/nc/ncappletwindow.cgi?param_action=install&url=&w=&win_url=&noapplet=1 (DSLoginWindowController.m:412)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.669 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -clearUserAgentCookie removing cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:1006)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.670 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: found DSID cookie in WebKit cache after page load (DSLoginWindowController.m:435)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.670 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Adding cookie with name DSID, domain ras.optus.com.au, and value <hidden> (DSSessionContext.m:81)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.670 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Creating a new DSID cookie (DSSessionContext.m:145)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.670 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -stopLoadingAndProcessContents:ofURL: processing https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/nc/ncappletwindow.cgi?param_action=install&url=&w=&win_url=&noapplet=1... (DSLoginWindowController.m:463)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.671 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -loginWindowController:setClientParameter:value: checking local and remote versions: client 19525 vs. server 19525 (NCController.m:1367)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.671 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -loginWindowController:setClientParameter:value: versions are in sync: client 19525 is compatible with IVE 19525; starting session (NCController.m:1388)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.671 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -loginWindowController:setClientParameter:value: saving locale preference (
    en
) as AppleLanguages for use on next launch. (NCController.m:1344)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.671 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCWhitelist.info +isAllowAdminListOnlyEnabled Admin whitelist does not exist (NCWhitelist.m:28)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.671 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCWhitelist.info +checkWhitelist:origin_site: whitelist: /usr/local/juniper/whitelist.txt does not exist (NCWhitelist.m:53)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.671 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -enterResolvingProxiesStateWithOldState: reconfiguring and resolving proxies (NCController+NCStateChanges.m:120)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.672 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -reconfigure Reconfiguring on en3 (NCController.m:829)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.683 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSHTTPSProxyResolver.info -resolveProxiesInBackground No HTTPS proxy (DSHTTPSProxyResolver.m:386)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.683 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -proxyResolverDidFinishResolving: dnsSuffix = optus.com.au, optusnet.com.au, o-zone.optusnet.com.au, alphawest.com.au, netops.local, count = 0 (NCController.m:1099)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.684 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSIPCConnection.info -_clearIPCBuffer: Clearing the IPC buffer (DSIPCConnection.mm:526)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.684 Network Connect[p492.t4871] separateserviceadapter.info Adding adapter as responder (NCSeparateServiceAdapter.mm:34)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.685 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCSeparateServiceAdapter.info Connecting with host ras.optus.com.au (NCServiceAdapter.mm:132)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.700 ncproxyd[p611.t771] ipsec.info New tunnel being created (tunnel.cpp:52)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.707 ncproxyd[p611.t771] routeutils.info Creating Desktop route table iterator (routeutils.cpp:289)

2015-06-01 12:59:09.836 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: loaded https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/home/starter0.cgi?check=yes (DSLoginWindowController.m:412)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.840 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didFinishLoadForFrame: found DSID cookie in WebKit cache after page load (DSLoginWindowController.m:435)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.840 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Adding cookie with name DSID, domain ras.optus.com.au, and value <hidden> (DSSessionContext.m:81)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.844 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSSessionContext.info -addCookieWithName:domain:value: Creating a new DSID cookie (DSSessionContext.m:145)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.904 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: loading https://ras.optus.com.au/dana/home/starter0.cgi... (DSLoginWindowController.m:257)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.905 Network Connect[p492.t4871] DSLoginWindowController.info -webView:didStartProvisionalLoadForFrame: setting cookie <NSHTTPCookie version:0 name:"DSUserAgent" value:"NcWin32" expiresDate:(null) created:2015-06-01 02:59:09 +0000 (4.5482e+08) sessionOnly:TRUE domain:"ras.optus.com.au" path:"/" isSecure:FALSE> (DSLoginWindowController.m:270)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.915 Network Connect[p492.t4871] separateserviceadapter.info Removing adapter as responder (NCSeparateServiceAdapter.mm:47)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.915 Network Connect[p492.t4871] separateserviceadapter.info Removing adapter as responder (NCSeparateServiceAdapter.mm:47)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.915 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCController.info -proxyMonitor:taskDidTerminateWithStatus: /usr/local/juniper/nc/7.1.0/ncproxyd terminated with exit code 11; in state 3; last-signal 0 (NCController.m:1137)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.915 Network Connect[p492.t4871] NCAdminFunctions.info calling ncproxyd to restore system configuration. (NCAdminFunctions.mm:52)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.937 ncproxyd-admintool[p613.t1291] ncproxyd.info looking for ncproxyd in 206 processes (ncproxyd.cpp:241)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.938 ncproxyd-admintool[p613.t1291] ipsec.info New tunnel being created (tunnel.cpp:52)
2015-06-01 12:59:09.944 ncproxyd-admintool[p613.t1291] routeutils.info Creating Desktop route table iterator (routeutils.cpp:289)

2015-06-01 12:59:10.110 Network Connect[p492.t70727] dsclient.info query_str = /dana/home/norefr.cgi?type=NC&action=stop (dsclient.cpp:911)
2015-06-01 12:59:10.115 Network Connect[p492.t70727] DSClientAdapter.info -sendSessionEndMessage Sent session end message (AM_NC/SESSION_STOP). (DSClientAdapter.mm:271)
2015-06-01 12:59:10.115 Network Connect[p492.t70727] DSClientAdapter.info -_threadEntry: Invalidated. Exiting thread. (DSClientAdapter.mm:192)
2015-06-01 12:59:10.182 Network Connect[p492.t4871] nc.mac.app.1203.error <DSError 0xdf783c0 domain=nc.mac.app code=1203 "/usr/local/juniper/nc/7.1.0/ncproxyd terminated with nonzero exit code 11; in state 0" userInfo={
    DSErrorClassName = NCController;
    DSErrorLocalizedAlertText = "A software error caused the tunneling service to terminate. See the Log Viewer for more information.";
    DSErrorLocalizedAlertTitle = "Your session terminated unexpectedly.";
    DSErrorLocalizedFirstButtonTitle = Continue;
    DSErrorLocalizedSecondButtonTitle = DSOptions;
    DSErrorMethodName = "proxyMonitor:taskDidTerminateWithStatus:";
    DSErrorStackBackTrace =     (
        "DSCreateStackBackTraceWithStack (in net.juniper.DSCoreServices) + 111",
        "DSFrameArrayWithStackBackTrace (in net.juniper.DSCoreServices) + 2567",
        "start (in Network Connect) + 31244",
        "start (in Network Connect) + 59928",
        "__57-[NSNotificationCenter addObserver:selector:name:object:]_block_invoke (in Foundation) + 50",
        "__CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__ (in CoreFoundation) + 20",
        "_CFXNotificationPost (in CoreFoundation) + 3713",
        "-[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] (in Foundation) + 92",
        "__39-[NSConcreteTask launchWithDictionary:]_block_invoke211 (in Foundation) + 168",
        "__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation) + 16",
        "__CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation) + 195",
        "__CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation) + 2165",
        "CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation) + 390",
        "CFRunLoopRunInMode (in CoreFoundation) + 123",
        "RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox) + 262",
        "ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox) + 494",
        "_BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox) + 99",
        "_DPSNextEvent (in AppKit) + 742",
        "-[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit) + 350",
        "-[NSApplication run] (in AppKit) + 907",
        "NSApplicationMain (in AppKit) + 2082",
        "start (in Network Connect) + 57362",
        "start (in Network Connect) + 270",
        "start (in Network Connect) + 41",
        "0x00000001 (in Network Connect)"
    );
} (NCController.m:1148)>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info ifconfig -a: lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info en0: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether b8:f6:b1:13:cc:11 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet6 fe80::baf6:b1ff:fe13:cc11%en0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet 169.254.94.100 netmask 0xffff0000 broadcast 169.254.255.255
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: active
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info en1: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether 32:00:1a:ce:9c:00 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect <full-duplex>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: inactive
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info en2: flags=8963<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   options=60<TSO4,TSO6>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether 32:00:1a:ce:9c:01 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect <full-duplex>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: inactive
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether 40:6c:8f:39:72:29 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet6 fe80::426c:8fff:fe39:7229%en3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet 211.29.157.23 netmask 0xffffff80 broadcast 211.29.157.127
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: active
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether ba:f6:b1:31:dd:00 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   Configuration:
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   member: en1 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info           ifmaxaddr 0 port 5 priority 0 path cost 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info           ifmaxaddr 0 port 6 priority 0 path cost 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: <unknown type>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: inactive
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info p2p0: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 2304
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether 0a:f6:b1:13:cc:11 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: inactive
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info awdl0: flags=8902<BROADCAST,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1452
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether 86:50:9b:4d:34:8b 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: inactive
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info bridge100: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   options=3<RXCSUM,TXCSUM>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   ether ba:f6:b1:31:dd:64 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet 192.168.2.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.2.255
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   inet6 fe80::b8f6:b1ff:fe31:dd64%bridge100 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0xb 
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   Configuration:
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info       ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   member: en0 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info           ifmaxaddr 0 port 4 priority 0 path cost 0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   nd6 options=1<PERFORMNUD>
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   media: autoselect
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info   status: active
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info netstat -rnf inet: -a: Routing tables
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info Internet:
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info Destination        Gateway            Flags        Refs      Use   Netif Expire
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info default            211.29.157.1       UGSc           95      221     en3
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info default            link#4             UCSI            1        0     en0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info default            link#11            UCSI            0        0 bridge1
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 10/24              link#5             USc             0        0     en1
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 10.0.0.56          11.11.11.11.11.11.11.11.11.11.11.1.80.0.5.14.5 UHS             0        0     en1
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 10.0.0.138         link#5             UHS             0        0     en1
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 10.105.96.63       link#1             UHS             0        0     lo0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 10.105.96.254      ff.ff.ff.ff.ff.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7c.0.5.14.7.0.0.0.7.0.6.1.3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.8.1.0.0.0.0.0.a6.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.dc.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.73.d7.6b.55.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.a6.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.11.53.fd.7.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.d3.1d.9d.1.7.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.7c.0.5.14.7.0.0.0.7.0.6.1.3.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.3.8.1.0.0.0.0.0.c5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.dc.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.82.d8.6b.55.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.c5.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.b4.5.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.11.6e.f2.9.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.10.2.0.0.d3.1d.9d.1.7.0.0 UHS             0        0     en1
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 127                127.0.0.1          UCS             0        0     lo0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH              3      187     lo0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 169.254            link#7             UCS             0        0     en3
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 169.254            link#4             UCSI            0        0     en0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 169.254.94.100/32  link#4             UCS             0        0     en0
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 192.168.2          link#11            UC              1        0 bridge1
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 192.168.2.2        90.8d.6c.af.ab.d4  UHLWIi          3       52 bridge1   1163
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 211.29.157/25      link#7             UCS             2        0     en3
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 211.29.157.1/32    link#7             UCS             1        0     en3
2015-06-01 12:59:10.191 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 211.29.157.1       0:19:a9:8:74:0     UHLWIir        94        0     en3    915
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 211.29.157.23/32   link#7             UCS             0        0     en3
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 211.29.157.104     10:dd:b1:ba:ca:4d  UHLWI           0        0     en3   1194
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info 211.29.157.127     ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff  UHLWbI          0        5     en3
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info resolv.conf: #
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info # Mac OS X Notice
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info #
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info # This file is not used by the host name and address resolution
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info # or the DNS query routing mechanisms used by most processes on
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info # this Mac OS X system.
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info #
2015-06-01 12:59:10.192 Network Connect[p492.t4871] diag.info # This file is automatically generated.
```

Comment: I have the same problem since last week. It was running on 10.10.3, now it's failing with "Your session terminated unexpectedly."